# Library or any API for plotting dendrograms

Tags: dendrogram

I have an MySQL database which contains some data,it interacts with JSP pages,the thing is that I have to plot dendrograms from various files stored in the database.

I found some java API for this like JTree or others, but I'm not familiar with java, so I am wondering if there is an alternative to do it with a CGI or php pages that call a program or something.

Any idea or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This is many months later, but the machine-learning toolkit orange: http://www.ailab.si/orange/

lets you draw dendrograms. You would not need many lines of python code to glue this together as a CGI program.